# Move objects by object fields inside array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, that represents data from a chart. I also have a varibale Timezone. How do I move objects that have sales > 0 according to the Timezone variable? So if Timezone = -5, all objects that have sales > 0 should move it's position -5 indexes. The numbering of the name field should remain intact, from 12 to 1 and from 1 to 11, but sales move according to the Timezone variable.[image]

Comment: do you have the data in text form? and the wanted result? what have you tried? what does not work?

Comment: What if new position is negative? What if new position (currentIndex - timeZone) is occupied by an object which has sales <=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

1. Create new array: `const result = new Array(yourObjectsArr.length);`
2. Go through `yourObjectsArr` first time:

```
yourObjectsArr.forEach((obj, key) => {
  if (obj.sales > 0) {
    // what if (key - timeZone) is negative?
    const result[key - timeZone] = obj;
  }
});
```

3. Go through `yourObjectsArr` second time and deal with all cases when sales <= 0. Mb it'd possible to do it in one loop, depends on which position should occupied these objects